# R elastic package error "Error: 404 - no such index"

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I've updated my elasticsearch to version 5.x! And tried to connect my R Studio(with elastic package). But it gives me an error  `Error: 404 - no such index`.
I connect like this:

```
elastic::connect(es_host = "http://kibana.smasell.com", es_port = "9200/es", es_user = "****", es_pwd = "****")
```

It gives me:

```
transport:  http 
host:       kibana.smasell.com 
port:       9200/es 
path:       NULL 
username:   ***** 
password:   <secret> 
errors:     simple 
headers (names):  NULL
```

And then try to search:

```
elastic::Search(index = "data_month_2016-01", size =1)
```

gives me

```
Error: 404 - no such index
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: First, try through the browser that whether data is coming or not.

Comment: `port` argument should be just the port, put the path in the `es_path` argument